# Nokogiri is not loading "browser" from Watir

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, watir, watir-webdriver

I have this so far:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'date'
require 'nokogiri'

browser = Watir::Browser.start 'https://example/ViewReport.aspx'

browser.link(:text, 'Combined Employee Performance Report').click

today = Date.today
yesterday = today.prev_day.strftime('%m' '%d' '%Y')

t = browser.text_field :id => 'UC255_txtStart'
t.set yesterday

t = browser.text_field :id => 'UC255_txtEnd'
t.set yesterday

btn = browser.button :value, 'Run Report'
btn.exists?
btn.click

page = Nokogiri::HTML.parse('browser')
links = page.css("a")
puts links.length
```

When I try to parse `browser`, the variable that Watir is using for the site URI, it gives me a blank HTML page.

Comment: Nokogiri doesn't open browsers, it parses HTML/XML text. What do you think it should do when you tell it to `Nokogiri::HTML.parse('browser')`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Problem**

When you do

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML.parse('browser')
```

You are asking Nokogiri to parse the string 'browser'.

**Solution**

What you actually want to parse is the html in the browser.

To get the browser's html, you do:

```
browser.html
```

So to parse it, you would do:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(browser.html)
```

Comment: I actually tried that earlier (and again now) and I'm still not getting the page's html.

Comment: Ahh, looks like you're, of course, right. I added the quotes around browser.html (and you didn't). I'm getting the html now. Thank you!